# Merging a branch with a reverted change

Tags: git, version-control

Here is the situation.

I accidentally committed to master branch which I actually wanted to commit to branch X.
Then I merge master to X then git revert the changes on master.

But eventually this X will be merged to master but then It won't merge this reverted change.

What is the most proper way to fix this?

Comment: `But eventually this X will be merged to master but then It won't merge this reverted change.` what does this mean? you said you already reverted the change on master

Comment: @Paolo What I mean is the change I reverted must be merged later but not right now. but since it was originally reverted, when X is merged to master it won't take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the history of the branch so that *to git*, it is like that is work that has never been merged into the branch. Suppose that the branch is 2 commits:

```
git checkout some-branch~2 # we start from the point where that work was started
git cherry-pick HEAD..some-branch
# that will create 2 new commits with the same stuff as the original 2
# but this is something that has never been merged
git branch something
```

This branch can be merged into `master`

Comment: In your answer some-branch is the branch X  on my question and the something is another newly created branch right?

Comment: yep, that's right.